# .CSS edit menu with wordpress using Custom.css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

All i want to do is just Center my menu on my stie . 
When i add :

```
.primary-menu { 
  float: none !important;
}
```

in my custom.css

just nothing happend.

when i add just :

```
.primary-menu { 
  float: right !important;
}
```

My menu is moving to right side of my page.
( I don't have access to files  , i can use only custom.css in my wordpress )

my website: http://test.projekt-tenis.pl/wordpress/

and screen:

[image]

can someone just look in google chrome and tell me what i should add to my `custom.css` to center this menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the `<a>` but the `<li>`:

```
.primary-menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.primary-menu .wbc_menu > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

Now in the website, it looks like:

[image: preview]

Is this what you need?

Comment: Man you are awesome!

Comment: Everything for you :) i'll have one more problem and last one gonna create topic late and give you link  here  :P

Comment: could you look at that? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150995/css-replace-item-in-menu-using-only-custom-css-in-wordpress