# Replace item in menu using only custom.css in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I would like to replace this image when I scroll  down on another image.

Firstly, the menu looks like:

[image]

And when I scroll little bit down menu looks like:

[image]

Is it possible to replace  using custom.css this item in menu? I just want to replace this picture on another picture. Is it possible to do by using only custom.css or do I need to have acces to files and use here java script?

When it's possible can somene just tell how?

Link to my site : http://test.projekt-tenis.pl/wordpress/

Comment: Being that you want to change an element attribute (`src`) and not a style property, your solution would likely be either impossible, or extremely ugly (hiding the source image yet still assigning a background image somehow). Furthermore, you'd need an ancestor-element to change so that you could reference the image conditionally. But, most importantly, you haven't given us enough information. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). *(Side-note: Java**Script** would make this entirely easier, yes. Java is completely different.)*

Comment: @KirkBeard Not to step on your toes here but I'm thinking JavaScript shouldn't even be tagged at all. OP was very specific in his request for a solution modifying a CSS file only, therefore I don't think the question merits the JS tag :)

Comment: edited. I just want to replace this image in the middle on the another picture. When i just scroll little page down menu is changed  : on white backgrtound and in the same time i want just change middle logo too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a whirl:

```
.is-sticky img.menu-image-title-hide {
    background: url(http://www.spiritvoyage.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/Screen-shot-2011-12-06-at-2.56.08-PM-150x150.png) no-repeat;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-left: 150px;
}
```

Should do the trick. It moves the original src image out of the way and adds a background image. As far as your user is concerned it'll just look like it flips from one image to the other.

It works because the class .is-sticky is added to the header on scroll by js.